# double execution

Tags: c#, events, keydown, onkeydown

I develop small application in C# but I've problem with events. My form have controlState property which describe current state of application. When application is in SEARCH state and I press enter it exec both KeyDown_Search and KeyDown_Idle method. When I add MessageBox.Show("anything"); at the end of KeyDown_eventManager problem doesn't exists - it exec only KeyDown_Search method.
What can I do to solve this problem?

```
enum ControlState {NO_SHOW, IDLE, SEARCH}

private ControlState controlState;

protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
  this.controlState = ControlState.IDLE;
  this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(KeyDown_eventManager);
}

void KeyDown_eventManager(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  switch (this.controlState)
  {
    case ControlState.SEARCH:
      this.KeyDown_Search(sender, e);
      break;
    case ControlState.NO_SHOW:
    case ControlState.IDLE:
      this.KeyDown_Idle(sender, e);
      break;
  }
}

void KeyDown_Search(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.KeyCode)
  {
    case Keys.Enter:
      this.textContent = this.db.searchList(this.textSearch);
      this.textSearch = null;
      this.controlState = ControlState.IDLE;
      break;
  }
  this.draw();
}

void KeyDown_Idle(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.KeyCode)
  {
    case Keys.Enter:
      this.controlState = ControlState.NO_SHOW;
      break;
  }
  this.draw();
}
```

Update: I add all application code. Maybe it's help to find solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using dbConnector;
using DX = Microsoft.DirectX;
using D3D = Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D;

namespace dbConnector
{
    public class dbText
    {
        public dbText()
        {

        }

        public string searchList(string keyword)
        {
            return "there will be connection to db";
        }
    }
}

namespace Rzutnik
{
    enum ControlState
    {
        NO_SHOW, IDLE, SEARCH
    }

    public partial class Display : Form
    {
        private D3D.Device device;
        private dbText db;
        private ControlState controlState;
        private D3D.Font textFont;
        private D3D.Font textSearchFont;
        private Rectangle textRect;
        private int textPosition;
        private bool textScrollingUp;
        private int textJump;
        private Timer textScrollingTimer;
        private Timer textAutocomplete;
        private int textScrollingTimerInterval;
        private string textContent;
        private string textSearch = null;

        public Display()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.controlState = ControlState.IDLE;
            this.InitializeDb();
            this.InitializeDevice();
            this.textInitialize();
            this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(KeyDown_eventManager);
            this.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(KeyUp_eventManager);
            this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(KeyPress_eventManager);
            this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(DisplayPaint);
            this.ResizeEnd += new EventHandler(DisplayResizeEnd);
        }

        protected void InitializeDb()
        {
            this.db = new dbText();
        }

        protected void InitializeDevice()
        {
            D3D.PresentParameters presentParams = new D3D.PresentParameters();
            presentParams.BackBufferFormat = D3D.Format.R5G6B5;
            presentParams.Windowed = true;
            presentParams.SwapEffect = D3D.SwapEffect.Discard;

            this.device = new D3D.Device(0, D3D.DeviceType.Hardware, this, D3D.CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, presentParams);
        }

        void KeyDown_eventManager(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (this.controlState)
            {
                case ControlState.SEARCH:
                    this.KeyDown_Search(sender, e);
                    break;
                case ControlState.NO_SHOW:
                    this.KeyDown_Idle(sender, e);
                    break;
                case ControlState.IDLE:
                    this.KeyDown_Idle(sender, e);
                    break;
            }

            //MessageBox.Show("anything");
        }

        void KeyUp_eventManager(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (this.controlState)
            {
                case ControlState.NO_SHOW:
                case ControlState.IDLE:
                    this.KeyUp_Idle(sender, e);
                    break;
            }
        }

        void KeyPress_eventManager(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (this.controlState)
            {
                case ControlState.NO_SHOW:
                case ControlState.IDLE:
                case ControlState.SEARCH:
                    this.KeyPress_Idle_Search(sender, e);
                    break;
            }
        }

        void KeyDown_Idle(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Up:
                    if (this.textScrollingTimer.Enabled == true)
                        return;
                    this.textStartScrollingUp();
                    break;
                case Keys.Down:
                    if (this.textScrollingTimer.Enabled == true)
                        return;
                    this.textStartScrollingDown();
                    break;
                case Keys.Enter:
                    this.controlState = ControlState.NO_SHOW;
                    break;
            }

            this.draw();
        }

        void KeyUp_Idle(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);

            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Up:
                case Keys.Down:
                    this.textStopScrolling();
                    break;
            }

            this.draw();
        }

        void KeyDown_Search(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Enter:
                    this.textContent = this.db.searchList(this.textSearch);
                    this.textSearch = null;
                    this.controlState = ControlState.IDLE;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                    break;
                case Keys.Back:
                    this.textSearch = this.textSearch.Substring(0, this.textSearch.Length - 1);
                    this.textAutocomplete.Stop();
                    this.textAutocomplete.Start();
                    if (this.textSearch.Length == 0)
                        this.controlState = ControlState.IDLE;
                    break;
            }
            this.draw();
        }

        void KeyPress_Idle_Search(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar != 8 && e.KeyChar != 13)
            {
                this.textSearch += e.KeyChar;
                this.textAutocomplete.Stop();
                this.textAutocomplete.Start();
                this.controlState = ControlState.SEARCH;
            }
        }

        public void drawSearch()
        {
            this.device.BeginScene();
            this.textSearchFont.DrawText(null, this.textSearch, new Point(10, this.ClientSize.Height - 10 - 9), Color.Red);
            this.device.EndScene();
        }

        public void drawText()
        {
            device.BeginScene();
            this.textFont.DrawText(null, this.textContent, this.textRect, D3D.DrawTextFormat.WordBreak, Color.White);
            device.EndScene();
        }

        public void draw()
        {
            device.Clear(D3D.ClearFlags.Target, Color.Black, 1.0f, 0);

            switch (this.controlState)
            {
                case ControlState.IDLE:
                    this.drawText();
                    break;
                case ControlState.SEARCH:
                    this.drawText();
                    this.drawSearch();
                    break;
            }

            device.Present();
        }

        void DisplayResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textInitializeRectangleSize();
            this.draw();
        }

        void DisplayPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            this.draw();
        }

        private void textInitialize()
        {
            this.textPosition = 0;
            this.textJump = 3;
            this.textContent = null;

            this.textAutocomplete = new Timer();
            this.textAutocomplete.Interval = 100;
            this.textAutocomplete.Tick += new System.EventHandler(textAutocomplete_Tick);

            this.textScrollingTimer = new Timer();
            this.textScrollingTimerInterval = 1;
            this.textScrollingTimer.Interval = this.textScrollingTimerInterval;
            this.textScrollingTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(textScrollingTimer_Tick);

            this.textInitializeRectangleSize();
            this.textInitializeFont();
        }

        void textAutocomplete_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textContent = this.db.searchList(this.textSearch.Trim());
            this.textAutocomplete.Stop();
            this.draw();
        }

        private void textInitializeRectangleSize()
        {
            this.textRect = new Rectangle(10, 10 + this.textPosition, this.ClientSize.Width - 20, this.ClientSize.Height - 20 + this.textPosition);
        }

        private void textInitializeFont()
        {
            System.Drawing.Font systemfont1 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12f, FontStyle.Regular);
            System.Drawing.Font systemfont2 = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 9f, FontStyle.Regular);
            this.textFont = new D3D.Font(this.device, systemfont1);
            this.textSearchFont = new D3D.Font(this.device, systemfont2);
        }

        void textScrollingTimer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.textScrollingUp == true)
                this.textPosition -= this.textJump;
            else
                this.textPosition += this.textJump;

            this.textInitializeRectangleSize();
            this.draw();
        }

        private void textStartScrollingUp()
        {
            this.textScrollingUp = true;
            this.textScrollingTimer.Start();
        }

        private void textStartScrollingDown()
        {
            this.textScrollingUp = false;
            this.textScrollingTimer.Start();
        }

        private void textStopScrolling()
        {
            this.textScrollingTimer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggest you clarify if this is a Windows Form, or if this is a UserControl ... or ... ? Just curious : why are you over-riding OnShown ?

Comment: You should attach the `KeyDown` handler in the Form's constructor, not inside `OnShown`. Search your code for occurences of `KeyDown_eventManager` to see that you are not attaching the handler twice.

Comment: This is Windows Form application and I use managed directx.
I move KeyDown handler to Form constructor but it's not solve my problem. I search my code for occurrence of KeyDown_eventManager but I find it only in 2 place - definition and attach

Comment: Look in the Designer.cs file.

Comment: I don't do anything in designer mode so designer.cs have contents as in new empty windows form project.

Comment: Suggestion : use Console.WriteLine("") when debugging event handlers, or set break points to halt in key places in your code to examine state, rather than using MessageBox.Show("") : calling 'MessageBox.Show is going to put your app in a different "state" vis-a-vis key-input, mouse-input, etc., and "interfere" with the stuff the event handler is doing, making it harder for you to "catch" what's really happening.

Comment: Thanks for help. I'm used to write application without debugger so I forget used it. In code I had  base.OnKeyDown(e);  in keyup event handler which make problems.  
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you add event listener in two places. Probably in the generated designer code as well as your OnShown method (and, btw, OnShown is an odd place to add event handlers).

Comment: Either that, or OnShown fires more than once

Comment: @Sander: it's fired only once, when the form is shown for the 1st time.

Comment: I don't think that problem is in add event in two places - when I add MessageBox.Show("anything"); it show only once.

Comment: Well, there are 3 alternatives: 1) The event fires twice, 2) You have omitted something important in the posted snipped, and 3) You have hit some strange compiler bug. 3) is very unlikely. Where did you add your MessageBox.Show() call?

Comment: at the end of KeyDown_eventManager method